# SQLite database cursor always returns 0 even though the table is filled correctly

Tags: c#, android, database, sqlite, xamarin

I have saved data in table PollCollection(PollID, PollName, VotingClass) and OptionCollection(OptionID, PollID, Option). I have a class called Poll, in which string PollTitle and LinkedList option can be saved (and others). I read my first PollName from PollCollection with appropriate VotingClass and then try to read Option from OptionCollection where PollID = PollCollection.PollID. However, my options cursor has a length of 0.

I know for a fact that the OptionCollection is saved properly, because in another piece of code I managed to run a select * query and printed all the appropriate values. At this point, I have no idea what am I missing. Also, I am working with Xamarin Android.

```
string pollquery = "";
        string optionsquery = "";
        pollquery = string.Format("select * from PollCollection where PollCollection.VotingClass = '{0}'", userclass);
        ICursor polls = MainActivity.sqlitedb.RawQuery(pollquery, null);
        if (polls.Count > 0)
        {
            polls.MoveToFirst();
            do
            {
                Poll currentpoll = new Poll();
                currentpoll.PollTitle = polls.GetString(polls.GetColumnIndex("PollName"));
                string pollid = polls.GetString(polls.GetColumnIndex("PollID"));
                optionsquery = string.Format("select Option from OptionCollection where OptionCollection.PollID = '{0}'", pollid);
                ICursor options = MainActivity.sqlitedb.RawQuery(optionsquery, new string[] { });
                options.MoveToFirst();
                do
                {
                    currentpoll.Options.AddLast(options.GetString(options.GetColumnIndex("Option")));
                } while(options.MoveToNext());
                polllist.AddLast(currentpoll);
            } while (polls.MoveToNext());
        }
```

Comment: use `[...] where PollCollection.VotingClass = ?` in `rawQuery` and read about the second parameter passed to that method (which means not  to use any `String#format` method)

Comment: But if I don't use string.Format, how do I edit it to include my variable?

Comment: did you read [rawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) documentation?

Comment: Yes I did, but I might be misunderstanding it then?

Comment: and what is the second parameter passed to `rawQuery` method?

Comment: Oh hell I am so stupid, I was told to use it empty but I guess it makes sense. Thanks! But also, can I ask why Cursor polls does not return an error when i use string.Format and Cursor options does?

Comment: i dont know, first try `selectionArgs`

Comment: Edited it, however, I still get the 0 index error.

Comment: use `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor` method and check the `logcat`, what do you see?

Comment: btw do not use `do {...} while` - use `while(cursor.moveToNext()) {...}` instead - your code will not work if the cursor has zero rows

Comment: It showed the data that is in the database meaning that the data is in the cursor. But now I do not get the zero index problem either.

Comment: good, now you can remove that `dumpCursor` method

Comment: I don't get why using it like this doesn't return me error but thanks for helping me! Was struggling with that message for quite a while.